# Tiny hiccups during youtube 4k hdr playback?

Tags: video, youtube, 4k-resolution, hdr

My setup is a Ryzen 2700x with an Nvidia 1070ti.

I have sufficient bandwidth (200Mbps) and the video loads really fast. When I start playing the video everything seemingly runs Every five seconds there is a really minor tiny hiccup in both sound and picture. As I said, the video is already buffered up really well and these keep occurring every four seconds.

Here is [a link to a 4K HDR video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVvEISFw9w0) as an example.

This does not happen during offline video playback.

My CPU and GPU usage are pretty high (50%) during playback.

Comment: What chipset is on your network interface? (Im thinking possibly along the line of interrupts on a cheap realtek card???) Alternatively this could be a software issue - what other software is running?

Comment: @davidgo
Not running any other software (that I know of). I'll add a screenshot of the processes from task manager (soon). The HDR works fine at 1440p. It buffers the data well in advance. My hunch is that the hiccup is a decoding issue.
I read this when I did the research on my own:

https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/8nv36x/youtube_hdr_support/

It seems "it is known" that HDR on Chrome is not terribly fast and requires a fast PC. I am wondering if the bottleneck is the CPU or the GPU or something else.

I would be happy to explore your speculation. How should I test?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up testing again with a Samsung Evo Plus (probably any nvme m.2 ssd would have worked) and they're completely gone! It appears there is a hidden hdd bottle neck even with SSDs somewhere in the decoding process.